# Unity3D - Set a (foreground) UI layer which ignores mouse clicks?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm currently writing up a UI-Centric game, and I've added a small image overlay over some elements on screen. However, the problem is that now I can't click any buttons behind this overlay image, regardless of transparency etc.

Just to chance it, I set up a new layer called "noUIclick" and set it to ignore every other layer under physics settings - long shot I know, but no dice. Tried also simply swapping to 3D view and moving the overlay image back on the z-axis.

Is there any easy way to set a layer for UI components which will entirely ignore/allow for passthrough of mouseclicks onto the buttons in the background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the `Image` component, uncheck `raycastTarget`.

Comment: Wow, that easy. Thanks!